# Influx - Help to choose in between Tag and Field

Tags: influx-db

I have the following columns:

'**datetime**', - which gives the time when the sensor values are recorded.

'**machineID**', - which gives the machine ID of the machine from where the sensor values are recorded.

'**volt**', '**rotate**', '**pressure**', '**vibration**' - 4 different sensor values measured for a particular Machine at a time.

Please let me know if I need to name datetime and MachineID coulumns under tag or fields.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a call considering below two scenarios.

1. If you need to run a **GROUPBY** clause on a particular column/field, then you need to create it as **Tag**, otherwise you won't be able to use **GROUPBY** clause.
2. Indexing: **Fields** cannot be indexed in influxdb. **Tag** are automatically indexed.

Also, influx by default creates a 'time' tag, so it's better while inserting you pass the value to 'time' instead of adding an extra column called 'datetime'